Where did the earliest Turing machine undecidability proofs appear?
It is common in any theoretical computer science textbook or class to prove the undecidability of various decision problems for Turing machines. It is often claimed that Turing himself established the undecidability of the problem "given a Turing machine M and input w, does M accept w?", as well as the "M halts on w" variant. (This is not exactly true, Turing proved that a similar-but-distinct problem was undecidable.)
However, I can't seem to find the origins of undecidability proofs for other decision problems: namely, given a Turing machine M,

does M accept all inputs?
does M accept no inputs?
does M recognize the same language as another Turing machine N?
does M recognize a subset of the language recognized by another Turing machine N?
and so on...

The fact that all of these problems are undecidable is a consequence of Rice's theorem, but I am interested in the first appearances of these problems in the literature - and perhaps the first explicit proofs of these undecidability results.
Additionally, I am interested in who first used mapping reductions (as in the work of Post) to reduce one problem to another in order to establish undecidability.

Lucas, S. (2021). The origins of the halting problem. Journal of Logical and Algebraic Methods in Programming, 121, 100687.

Thank you for the reference. But that paper, while comprehensive, focuses on the halting problem and not the matters I outlined in my question.

A brief but useful historical attribution of undecidability results can be found on page 216 of Hopcroft, Ullmann (1979) Introduction to Automata Theory, Languages, and Computation, Addison-Wesley. A book tracing the early period is an annotated anthology by Davis, M. (1965). The undecidable: Basic papers on undecidable propositions, unsolvable problems and computable functions. Raven Press.
